How does Classical Sanskrit deal with doubly embedded clauses?
I don't think I've ever seen a sentence with an iti-clause embedded inside another iti-clause, but I'm not sure how else you would translate a sentence like:
"Devadatta seems to be believed to want to eat."
Would it be grammatically incorrect, or just stylistically questionable, to translate this as something like:
देवदत्तो भोक्तुमिच्छतीति मत इति प्रतिभाति
If not, is there another way to translate it using a single sentence?
To give some context to my question, my curiosity was piqued by this passage in Jackendoff and Culicover's book Simpler Syntax, regarding the f-structure tier in lexico-functional grammar:

The level of f-structure
permits the grammar to manipulate the assignment of semantic arguments to
the grammatical functions subject, object, and indirect object; and in turn
grammatical function assignment determines syntactic position, case-marking,
and agreement. Such a treatment escapes the problems illustrated above by
virtue of the fact that (a) a phrase can be a semantic argument of one clause but
have a grammatical function in another, and (b) a syntactic dummy can have a
grammatical function without having a semantic function. Hence manipula
tions
such as passive and raising, which affect grammatical functions, are not
confined to semantic arguments of the clause being manipulated.

As Sanskrit seems to have a much stricter correspondence between syntactic and semantic argument structure than English, I'm not sure if a Sanskrit grammarian would have any need to posit f-structure. Are there any sentences where, e.g., the passive, is not formed by, e.g., simply promoting the lower-ranked semantic argument of the verb to subject position?

“Devadatta seems to be believed to want to eat” is not grammatical in English either. You cannot combine seems to + [infinitive] with the passive construction [subject] is believed to [infinitive]; you’d have to instead use a that-clause with an expletive it as subject: “It seems to be believed that Devadatta wants to eat”.

@JanusBahsJacquet Really? It sounds grammatical to me, a native speaker. As does "It seems that Devadatta is believed to want to eat", from which the original sentence can be derived by ordinary raising.

Hmm… Google does seem to find a few hits of this type seemingly written by native speakers, including an article about wh-clefting (p. 224, example 22) – though this article then goes on to label “What he was doing turned out to be washing himself” as ungrammatical (example 26), and I find that example perfectly fine, so it seems it’s less than cut and dry… ‘Seems to be believed to [inf]’, while understandable, is at the very least borderline ungrammatical to me.

I'm sure it's as understandable as the English version. Using your own chosen way of translating it, why not the following?
देवदत्तो भोक्तुकामो मतः प्रतिभाति
(Devadatta) (Eating-desirous) (is believed) (it appears)
where implicitly it could be देवदत्तः भोक्तुकामः (इति जनैः) मतः प्रतिभाति (मे). I'd probably understand from context what was going on either way. Multiple इति within a sentence don't necessarily imply a nested structure (see here for example) but I don't think there's ambiguity here.
